# Convergence with Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, ssl

On many Linux distributions by default there is only Firefox 3.6. However, when I try to install [Convergence](http://convergence.io/) I get:

[image: Convergence 0.08 could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 3.6.24]

How can I install Convergence on a distro that runs Firefox 3.6 (e.g. Scientific-Linux 6.1 or Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)?

Comment: It's going to be unnecessarily painful, since the web site provides no list of supported platforms.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/moxie0/Convergence/tree/master/client) is available, so you can compile it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this: [FF Version Compatibility Info Needed](https://github.com/moxie0/Convergence/issues/29), you can't run that add-on on Firefox 3.6. You'll need to get Firefox 4 or above.

Answer (score 6):

It's **never** recommended to use an outdated web-browser, because of security concerns. You obviously could recompile the source, specifically you would need to edit `install.rdf`.

But It goes without saying, rigging the extension to run on a considerably outdated browser is not the best solution.  It might not even be possible, if any required features are absent in 3.6.  In regards to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, a good Mozilla Team PPA exists, you can install the newest stable Firefox simply.

Open the terminal with *Applications → Accessories → Terminal.*, and then run these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

If you want to update Firefox on Scientific Linux 6.1, I'm not informed of the automated methods.  Although, firefox is distributed compiled, so you just need to install it from a .tar.gz.  Another user posted about his update at [Are there any fresh versions of Firefox for Scientific-Linux [or RHEL] available offically?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28312/are-there-any-fresh-versions-of-firefox-for-scientific-linux-or-rhel-available)